# How to validate JWT token in Keycloak using Java SDK?

Tags: java, keycloak, openid-connect

I’m pretty savvy with OAuth 2/OIDC but new to Keycloak. I have a need to authenticate a user given a JWT token.

Normally I’d hit the `userInfo` endpoint but in the Java SDK I don’t see a way to do that?
Is there such a method call and/or a local library call that will just let me validate the JWT token string (so I don’t have to pull the public keys remotely to verify the signature?)

Comment: Normally this work is done for you by the Keycloak adapter, cf. https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#java-adapters. You have everything at your disposal (and authentication is automatically handled generally - that's one goal) when your adapter is integrated to your application and correctly configured.

Comment: Thanks - is there some kind of documentation e.g. a sample project with dependencies that shows how to use the Java adapters. Right now I'm just pulling in various Jars and not really sure if I am doing the right thing e.g. implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-core:10.0.1'
  implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:10.0.1'

Comment: It depends on which adapter you choose. What kind of application are you securing? Or have you found the more suitable adapter already? Generally you will need https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-adapter-core. Then you add more dependencies according to your needs (i.e. admin-client -> if you are using Keycloak Admin CLI, keycloak-authz-client if you are using Keycloak Authorization Services). There is extended documentation on these components.

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointer to keycloak-adapter-core - I did some googling but could not find the documentation for that library (although I've found docs for the other components).

Comment: I'm not sure about what more do you need. Everything is in the official Keycloak documentation. Starting from the adapters doc you will know which one to choose and how to install/integrate it into your apps. Then you just need to configure the adapter often based on a JSON document. All parameters and properties of the configuration are described throughout the official Keycloak docs. Usually you will find there everything you need. https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/. Enjoy

Comment: No worries - thanks I was able to figure it out

Comment: Great :) Now the fun can start ^^

Answer (score 0):

With Keycloak 16.1.1 jar libraries, this is what worked for me (although it does pull the public keys off the server behind the scenes):

```
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment;
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder;
import org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier;
...

KeycloakDeployment depl = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(...);
String tokenToVerify = ...;

try{
    var tok = AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(tokenToVerify, depl);
    // passed
    tok.getPreferredUsername(); // user name
    tok.getSubject();           // keycloak user id
}
catch( VerificationException e){
    // failed
}
```